# Gradle - how to capture Gradle Sync error message from build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

In Android Studio, when I hit "Gradle Sync" button in the toolbar:
[image]

I can see the Gradle Sync event logs:
[image]

If Gradle sync completes and an error occurred, the "Messages Gradle Sync" window pops up:
[image]

How do I capture this "Failed to resolve" message?

Comment: What do you mean by capture? You redacted the failed to resolve "thing", what is it?

Comment: I want to grab the String "Failed to resolve....". I'm assuming this message comes from a Throwable object. So essentially, I want to know how to catch a failure during the "Gradle Sync" operation